# T-SQL Updated date field not the same as date format in select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime-format

In a SQL Server 2008 database I have a Fiscal Year table where the end_date for each fiscal period is set up wrong. The period start_date is the first day of a calendar month at midnight in the format smalldatetime (`2015-01-01 00:00:00`). The period end_date is **supposed** to be the last second of the last day of the start_date's month (`2015-01-31 23:59:59`). The data type for both fields is smalldatetime.

The following gives me the desired date and time that I would **like** to put in the end_date field:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,start_date)+1,0))
```

But it adds on milliseconds to the end of the time: `2015-01-31 23:59:59.000`

When I try converting or casting that as smalldatetime to omit the milliseconds it sets the time to *midnight* of the last day of the start_date's month: `2015-01-31 00:00:00`. This also happens if I just update the end_date field with the code in the select statement above.

How can I update the end_date with the correct format and value (`2015-01-31 23:59:59`)?

Comment: You seem to be confusing a [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) with a _format_ for displaying a value. Your application can display an integer with three decimal places, but it doesn't alter the precision of the underlying data type.

Comment: Why do you need the end_date to be the "end" of the day? This is problematic because the "end" of the day has different meanings depending on the data type. You should always use whole dates and open-ended ranges; avoid all this "last millisecond of the day" hooey just so you can use BETWEEN. If the last day is Jan 31 then just store Jan 31 and have the queries do `< DATEADD(DAY, 1, end_date)`. Or don't bother storing the end (do you really need to know the last day of a month?) - just use `>= start_date AND < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, start_date)`.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't realize that smalldatetime doesn't store seconds. KekuSemau's answer wasn't quite the right answer, but it did make me realize I wasn't trying to do the right thing, given the datatype of the column I had to update (No, I couldn't change the datatype of the column).

All I had to do was adjust the query to subtract a **minute** versus a **second**, which the smalldatetime field will work with:

```
cast(DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,start_date)+1,0)) as smalldatetime)
```

So I ended up updating the end_date column with `2015-01-31 23:50:00`, as required.

Answer (score 4):

[smalldatetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) does not store seconds, it's always `00`. That's why there's an automatic conversion when you subtract one second.
If you want to store seconds, you have to convert the columns to a different data type.